# Define zipper function in Racket

Tags: racket

I'm having trouble define a function that can do the same functionalities as zipper in Racket. So far I have this:

```
(define (zipper lst1 lst2)
  (match* [lst1 lst2]
    [{'()'()} '()]
    [{(cons hd1 tl1) (cons hd2 tl2)}
      (cons (list hd1 d2)
            (zipper tl1 tl2))]))
```

Can someone explain where I'm going wrong here. I want it to look like this:

```
> (zipper '(1 2 3 4) '(a b c d))
'((1 a) (2 b) (3 c) (4 d))
```

Comment: What do you want the function `zipper` to do?

Comment: @Majora320I want the zipper to do this                                                                               > (zipper '(1 2 3 4) '(a b c d))
   '((1 a) (2 b) (3 c) (4 d)).

Answer (score 6):

You can use `map` combined with `list` to have this functionality.

```
> (map list '(1 2 3 4) '(a b c d))
'((1 a) (2 b) (3 c) (4 d))
```

So, if you want to make it a single function zipper, it would look something like:

```
(define (zipper . args)
  (apply map list args))
```

This function works the same as `map list`:

```
> (zipper '(1 2 3 4) '(a b c d))
'((1 a) (2 b) (3 c) (4 d))
```

Comment: I realise this is somewhat late, but please could you explain what the `.` is doing in the definition of `zipper`. I'm new to Racket, and trying to learn as much as I can. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You were pretty close:

```
(define (zipper lst1 lst2)
  (match* [lst1 lst2]
    [{'() '()} '()]  
    [{(cons hd1 tl1) (cons hd2 tl2)}   
     (cons (list hd1 hd2)
           (zipper tl1 tl2))]))
```

I changed `d2` to `hd2`.